# Display isolines at fixed z using plotly or d3 contour plot or interpolation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

Given a set of data z like this:

```
z: [[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
       [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
       [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
       [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
       [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]]
```

[image: Contour plot]

Is there a way to fix a value of z and to trace the isoline and get the values x, y in the contour graph. For example, I have two lines in which z=4 and z=6, I want to have the value of x, y and to trace the isoline correspondant when z=5.5 .

You can have a sample of code below.

```js
var data = [ {
  z: [[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
       [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
       [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
       [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
       [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]],
  type: 'contour',
  colorscale: 'Jet',
  contours:{
    coloring: 'lines',
    showlabels: true
  }
}];

var layout = {
  title: 'Contour Lines'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="myDiv"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to fix the value of z in plotly contour plot. Here is my code:

```js
var data = [ {
  z: [[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
       [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
       [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
       [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
       [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]],
  type: 'contour',
  colorscale: 'Jet',
 autocontour: true,
   ncontours: 1,
   zmin: 5,
   zmax: 5.1,
   type: 'contour',
   showscale: false,
   contours: {
    coloring: 'lines',
    showlabels: true}
}];

var layout = {
  title: 'Contour Lines'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="myDiv"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

The key if you use plotly is to test all the attributes combinations stored in the [reference documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/)